# android ViewPager with ImageView child views - touch events are not passed to childrens

Tags: java, android, eclipse, touch

I have ViewPager view with RelativeLayout child views. The child view contains an ImageView and TextView. The problem is that event if I set setOnTouchListener to ImageView, it is not called when touching the ImageView. I think the problem is related to the fact that ViewPager intercepts touch events and does not pass it further to child views. Is there a way to control  whether ViewPager can pass touch events to child views?

Comment: Try to use this: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920137/android-viewpager-and-horizontalscrollview>

This works for me.

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122460/viewpager-intercepts-all-x-axis-ontouch-events-how-to-disable ; Which fixed my issue