# onTouchEvent is getting executed when page is swiped using ViewPager and PassByValue

Tags: android, android-viewpager, touch-event, pass-by-value

In my project have used onTouchEvent for detecting touch on the screen and doing action accordingly , and have used viewPager for swipe action. Problem is on swipe the touch actions are getting executed. so find the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122460/viewpager-intercepts-all-x-axis-ontouch-events-how-to-disable)  solved it. But my new Problem to it is the touch is getting disabled after once TouchEvent.Action_up gets executed. code is as follows:

```
parent.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch(event.getAction())
        {
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
                awesomePager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            awesomePager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
             if(flag)
             {
               upperdock.setClickable(false);
                upperdock.bringToFront();
                tocparent.bringToFront();
                tocbottom.bringToFront();
                upperdock.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
                tocparent.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                tocbottom.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                flag=false;
             }
             else
             {

                parent.bringToFront();
                upperdock.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
                tocparent.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
                tocbottom.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
                flag=true;
             }
             break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            awesomePager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
             break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

In the above code if i return false Action_up is not getting executed.. if i return true Action_cancel is not getting executed..that is pass by value is the problem in there.

Answer (score 2):

i change something for this.

not use 
`awesomePager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)`,
just use `return true`.

in the **activity** define a **boolean sroll** ;

set **sroll = positionOffset != 0.0** in **ViewPager.onPageScrolled**
and i override **onTouchEvent** in which the **view** in the **ViewPager**.

now you can check **if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && !sroll)** to decide the event whether will triggered

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem! For me this worked very well....

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        break;
    }

 case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:{
        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        break;

}

case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{

 //delete  awesomePager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
 //you don't need it here!
                 .
                 .
            do your stuff....
                 .

}
```

return your whole onTouch methode as true and not false...

```
return true;
```