# How to use Swipe Gestures on Android Fragments (with Tabs)

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, gestures

I saw an excellent guide in using gestures for Android app's.... over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection).

However, I could not adapt it to my situation which is bit more complicated.  I have a FragmentActivity with two inner Fragment classes (also using support library, tabs, and viewpager).

There are two tabs (one for each inner Fragment class).  When you are on Tab One and swipe right to left, using Viewpager, it swipes to the right tab--that works good.  *What I want to add is this*: **If you are on tab one, and swipe from left-to-right, it simply finish()'s the activity** and takes the user back to a ListActivitry where they came from.

I am not sure if the above linked question refers to this situation, but I sure couldn't get any of the suggestions to work.  It seems I need to call this in the left tab fragment, and not the "parent" FragmentActivity? Can someone guide me on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this approach to allow or deny pager intercept your swipes

```
 pager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
```

Take a look at this post [ViewPager intercepts all x-axis onTouch events. How to disable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122460/viewpager-intercepts-all-x-axis-ontouch-events-how-to-disable)

Comment: Thanks, I will mark correct when I can get working.  So basically, this overrides the Viewpager? So I can say something like "if (scroll right) switch tabs, if (scroll left) cancel viewpager and finish activity"?