# ScrollView is catching touch event for google map

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a horizontal scroll view that contains a hierarchy of viewgroups and then finally a google map. My problem is that the HSV is catching the left-right drag that's meant for the map. I've tried

```
    hsv.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
```

and even

```
    mapView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
```

but to no avail. Is there anything I'm doing wrong here? Or can you suggest another solution?

I think this should have been my original question: How do I implement the solution posted here [Mapview inside a ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546108/mapview-inside-a-scrollview). Specifically, where do I put the code?

Comment: Checkout another working solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17317176/989418

Comment: Nothing new to other answers but I've just created a Gist on how I solved this:
https://gist.github.com/Sottti/890daaeead1bd4784dfce7066a9011aa

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems you on the right way, but you should call requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true) method on every touch event (see [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent%28boolean%29)). Try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122460/viewpager-intercepts-all-x-axis-ontouch-events-how-to-disable)

*Updated:*

Try this out:

```
final HorizontalScrollView hsv = ...
final MapView mapView = ...

mapView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                hsv.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                hsv.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                break;
        }
        return mapView.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you help me out a bit more, please? Another problem I have is that I don't know where in the project I should put the code. I've read so many solutions to this but I really don't know where to put the code I've seen.

Comment: This is not working for me, the event is never called.

Answer (score 4):

For google map v2, follow the solution is [this tutorial](http://www.londatiga.net/it/programming/android/how-to-make-android-map-scrollable-inside-a-scrollview-layout/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to create custom MapView. Follow the code snippet provided below

```
public class AppMapView extends MapView {

    public AppMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
               System.out.println("unlocked");
               this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
               break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
               System.out.println("locked");
               this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
               break;
       }
       return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
   }
}
```

In XML follow code below:

```
<com.tech.linez.brixlanepassenger.custom_views.AppMapView
   android:id="@+id/map_ride_route"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="220dp"
   android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

try to override the onTouch of the map and always return true from it.