# When i put map inside Scrollview, it will move horizontally but can not move vertically

Tags: android, dictionary, scrollview

```
<ScrollView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" > 
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/below_layout_1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_background" >
                <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                    android:id="@+id/mpDelivery"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:clickable="true" >
                </com.google.android.maps.MapView>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/zoom"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout></ScrollView>
```

Here is my XML File.
So when i click on the map, it moves horizontally means left to right. Is there a way to move the MapView in both direction scrolling inside the ScrollView ?
How can i do that? 
Thanks in Advance....

Comment: Hey, did you get a solution for this? I have also same issue. Please help me on this.

Comment: No.. still now i didn't find any solution for this problem..

Comment: Try this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546108/mapview-inside-a-scrollview

Comment: Nothing new to other answers but I've created a Gist on how I solved this.
https://gist.github.com/Sottti/890daaeead1bd4784dfce7066a9011aa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other solutions from this site:

[MapView inside a ScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546108/mapview-inside-a-scrollview/21669595#21669595)

[ScrollView is catching touch event for google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025859/scrollview-is-catching-touch-event-for-google-map?lq=1)

And for android map v2, follow [this solution](http://www.londatiga.net/it/programming/android/how-to-make-android-map-scrollable-inside-a-scrollview-layout/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/below_layout_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

         <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                    android:id="@+id/mpDelivery"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:clickable="true" >
                </com.google.android.maps.MapView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/zoom"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="center" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Actually,i have lots of data on that layout and bottom of the layout MapView is shown. So I have to compulsory take ScrollView as top most layout.. so that's problem Andy.

Comment: @Dhruv comments is same to my issue.