# How to use MapFragment inside Scrollview?I am Using the getMapFragment() method.

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, scrollview, mapfragment

In my application I am using `MapFragment` inside `Activity` class.In layout file the `fragment` inside the `ScrollView`.when I am touching the Map,It leads to scroll the page I cannot access the Map to Zoom In,Zoom Out,Move the Places.Only `ScrollView` focus in this layout.

MapFragment:

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

I tried the Below Answer for My problem.But it's not working for me.
( Don't post the Below Answer.Because It will for `Mapview`)

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
int action = ev.getAction();
switch (action) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
    this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    break;

case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
    this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
    break;
}

// Handle MapView's touch events.
super.onTouchEvent(ev);
return true;
}
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525066/how-to-set-google-map-fragment-inside-scroll-view

Comment: @sasikumar I tried this.it's not working.bcs it was using getSupportFragmentManager() but i am using getFragmentManager()

Comment: you can change like that

Comment: @sasikumar this code use google map.