# Unable to start activity...Attempt to invoke virtual method...MapFragment.getMapAsync

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

My Application keeps crashing once it opens in nexus 6. The Problem is with getMapAsync().

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap mMap; //member variable
    private static final int ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST = 9001; //constant to request certain king of dialog box definition from google play services lib
    private static final double
            AJAX_LAT = 43.851063,
            AJAX_LNG = -79.019737;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (servicesOK()) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            if (initMap()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                gotoLocation(AJAX_LAT, AJAX_LNG, 13);

                //as of now user must grand permissions to app from phone settings
                try {
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "My Location not enabled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Map not connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Services not OK!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    //get a reference to the map object
    public boolean initMap() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map); mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }
        return (mMap != null);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

    }

    //check to see if the google services are ok
    public boolean servicesOK() {

        GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int isAvailable = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        // handle 3 different possibility
        if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { //everything ok, user can make mapping request
            return true;
        } else if (googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(isAvailable)) { //error user can do something about
            Dialog dialog = googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this, isAvailable, ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST);
            dialog.show(); //google play services lib delivers correct dialog box telling user what to do
        } else { //something wrong, user cant do anything about
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to mapping service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Below is the error i get

```
Process: com.example.suhail.onmyway, PID: 27425
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.suhail.onmyway/com.example.suhail.onmyway.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.suhail.onmyway.MainActivity.initMap(MainActivity.java:89)
    at com.example.suhail.onmyway.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

i have a button in activity_main.xml that once clicked opens another layout where a fragment is included

Comment: Usually with `AppCompatActivity`, you use `SupportMapFragment` and `getSupportFragmentManager()`. Beyond that, you might wish to post your `activity_main` layout.

Comment: i used SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mMap = mapFragment.getMap();  before,but getMap() is now deprecated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Put setContentView out of if block
It crashes from line 89
What is code of this line ?

------------ Update ------------

Use It :

```
            GoogleMap map = ((WorkaroundMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            final LatLng GOOGLE_MAP_POSITION = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            Log.d("GOOGLE_MAP", "lat : " + lat + " , lng : " + lng);
            if (map != null) {
                map.clear();
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(GOOGLE_MAP_POSITION)
                        .title("Title")
                        .snippet("Content Goes Here")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
            }
            MapsInitializer.initialize(this);
            // Move the camera instantly to target with a zoom of 14.
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(GOOGLE_MAP_POSITION, 50));
            // Zoom in, animating the camera, Change 14 to Zoom in And Zoom Out
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14), 2000, null);

            int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
            if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
                Log.e("DETAIL_ACTIVITY", "Google Play Services Util Available SUCCESS : "+resultCode);
            }else{
                Log.e("DETAIL_ACTIVITY", "Google Play Services Util Available Problem : "+resultCode);
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, 1);
            }
```

Also `WorkaroundMapFragment` is a Custom Class that Let you to use map inside ScrollView

To use it [check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30525471/2897869).

Comment: line 89 MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map); mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `mapFragment` is null, also incorrect `getMapAsync` usage, you must use all that belongs to map only after you receive the map, so you must act only after this call back is called:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

}
```

add all next initialisations in runnable and call it after

```
mMap = googleMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this to your `activity_main.xml`

```
<fragment 
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: i have a button in activity_main.xml that once clicked opens another layout where a fragment is included
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchButton" />