# How to get vertical scrolling to work for GoogleMap in ScrollView using Google Play Services 9.2.0?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a GoogleMap in a ScrollView. Vertically scrolling the map does not work as it scrolls the ScrollView instead.

I previously solved this by using a similar workaround to the one provided in: [how to set google map fragment inside scroll view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525066/how-to-set-google-map-fragment-inside-scroll-view/30525471#30525471)

But, that uses getMap() which was deprecated, and is no longer in 9.2.0.

Downgrading to 9.0.0 allows the workaround to work, which I was doing, but now I want to use Google's Awareness API in v9.2.0, so this workaround doesn't work anymore.

I've looked around and I can't find any recent answers on the topic, so does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Why can't use use getMapAsync() and do the same thing?  I don't see how it would be a problem....

Comment: I moved my code to the right place and moved the sections after the getMapAsync() into onMapReady and everything works fine. IDK why I didn't think of that. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do if you already have the workaround made, is use getMapAsync() instead of getMap and then put the parts after that into onMapReady().

If you don't have the workaround made, check the link in the question for an example