# Google Maps Inside A ScrollView For Fragments

Tags: java, android, google-maps, scroll, scrollview

I want to be able to have a Google Maps fragment inside another fragment that is in a ScrollView. I can Scroll down the fragment perfectly, however, when I come to move inside the map It is still in the ScrollView and I have to use two fingers to move around the map.

I have found another answer that shows and provides code that allows you to scroll around the map whilst having a scroll view.

**Answer I have been following:**
[how to set google map fragment inside scroll view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525066/how-to-set-google-map-fragment-inside-scroll-view?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

The answer has put a `.getMap()` which I don't understand where It has came from. Additionally I am unable to get the solution working for my needs.

Here is the code that I have so far:

**Inside onCreateView, in PostAJobFragment**

```
if (gMap == null)
        {
            getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback()
            {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
                {
                    gMap = googleMap;
                }
            });

            try
            {
                gMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                gMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                mScrollView = view.findViewById(R.id.advertScrollView); //parent scrollview in xml, give your scrollview id value

                ((WorkaroundMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                        .setListener(new WorkaroundMapFragment.OnTouchListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onTouch()
                            {
                                mScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                            }
                        });
            } catch(NullPointerException e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "Map Creation Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

**WorkAroundClass, to get the map to scroll independently of the ScrollView**

```
public class WorkaroundMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment
{
    private OnTouchListener mListener;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstance) {
        View layout = super.onCreateView(layoutInflater, viewGroup, savedInstance);

        TouchableWrapper frameLayout = new TouchableWrapper(getActivity());

        frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

        ((ViewGroup) layout).addView(frameLayout,
                new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        return layout;
    }

    public void setListener(OnTouchListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnTouchListener {
        public abstract void onTouch();
    }

    public class TouchableWrapper extends FrameLayout {

        public TouchableWrapper(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mListener.onTouch();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mListener.onTouch();
                    break;
            }
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        }
    }
}
```

**PostAJobFragment XML Code**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.kitkat.crossroads.Jobs.PostAnAdvertFragment">


    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/advertScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">
```

// Other Widgets Here

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/map"
                    tools:context="com.kitkat.crossroads.Jobs.PostAnAdvertFragment"
                    android:name="com.kitkat.crossroads.ExternalClasses.WorkaroundMapFragment" />
```

**My Question Is Different as I am using this in fragments and are getting errors with previous solutions posted**

Comment: it is a bad UI/UX to have scrollable map area insde a scrollview.

Comment: The user on the PostAJobFragment can enter the jobs name, description etc and then select a location from a map. If I put the map on a seperate fragment, I will have to pass all the JobInformation into the MapFragment and back again to repopulate the PostAJobFragment, which is too much memory and inefficent and could produce errors. I therefore, must put it on the same page.

Comment: I have relooked over the answer provided (The other question) and typed in the code given.

When I type in getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap(). getSupportFragmentManager is red as I'm working in a fragment. I tried using getFragmentManger but that makes .getMap() unavaliable

Comment: what if you keep your map pinned on the top and let the scrollview be below it. 

like this maybe? http://cdn.techpp.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Custom-Names-Header.png

Comment: Try maybe `SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            map = mapFrag.getMap();`

Comment: I have found the solution, the getMap method no longer works from android 9.2 onwards. I changed it to getMapAsync and added all code inside the onMapReady method. Thanks for your advice @Deepakkaku