# How to apply com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView inside scrollview?

Tags: android, scrollview, android-mapview

I am trying to implement the `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView` to `Scrollview` but whenever I want to navigate on the map the scrollview always get in the way when i scrolldown or scrollup. I tried to search for some answers but most of them are about the `fragment` map not using the `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView`. Can you please explain to me how can i  achieve this?

**XML file**

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

 <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/tracking_map"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView5"
        tools:context=".Activity.UserMapActivity" />

</ScrollView>
```

**JAVA CLASS**

```
public class OngoingOrderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMapView = findViewById(R.id.tracking_map);
        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(OngoingOrderActivity.this.getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMapView.onResume();

            mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {

            }
        });


}
}
```

Comment: this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525066/how-to-set-google-map-fragment-inside-scroll-view/30525471

Comment: map and scrollview both are scrollable. Putting one scrollable view into another is not a good idea