# MapView inside NestedScrollView not scrolling

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, google-play-services, android-maps-v2

Inflating my Mapview in xml like this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv_offers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="56dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.xys.widgets.CustomMapView
                android:id="@+id/mapView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="125dp"/>


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

And i have implemented the Custom Mapview as follows:-

```
public class CustomMapView extends MapView {

    private ViewParent mViewParent;

    public CustomMapView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void setViewParent(@Nullable final ViewParent viewParent) { //any ViewGroup
        mViewParent = viewParent;
    }

    public CustomMapView(Context context, GoogleMapOptions options) {
        super(context, options);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (null == mViewParent) {
                    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    Timber.d("Inside if of action down");
                } else {
                    mViewParent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    Timber.d("Inside else of action down");
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (null == mViewParent) {
                    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    Timber.d("Inside if of action up");
                } else {
                    mViewParent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    Timber.d("Inside else of action up");
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

And intilized my mapview in onCreate() of my Activity

```
mapView = (CustomMapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        GoogleMap googleMap = mapView.getMap();

        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);

        mapView.setViewParent(nestedScrollContainer);
```

Where `nestedScrollContainer` is my nested scrollView.Tried many workarounds provided in SO but cant seem to get a workaround for scrolling issue.Help would be appreciated!Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of your `CustomMapView`?

Comment: CustomMapView is nothing but extension of MapView with custom touch interceptors for enabling scrolling inside the scrollview

Comment: I have the same issue, but I noticed if I postpone the mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState); call like 500ms after onActivityCreated call in my fragment for example, it's working correctly. So far I didn't find a clean solution for this issue.

Comment: Check this and let me know if you have any doubts.


  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974983/google-maps-api-v2-supportmapfragment-inside-scrollview-users-cannot-scroll-th/53411743#53411743

Answer (score 8):

In your code `MapView` inside `NestedScrollView--> LinearLayout--> com.xys.widgets.CustomMapView` Two level hierarchy.

So in your case you can access NestedScrollView like below

```
getParent().getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
```

Change this line
`getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);` to this

```
getParent().getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
```

Below is full code for your case

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.xys.widgets.CustomMapView
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="125dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

`

```
public class CustomMapView extends MapView {

        private ViewParent mViewParent;

        public CustomMapView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public CustomMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public CustomMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }

        public void setViewParent(@Nullable final ViewParent viewParent) { //any ViewGroup
            mViewParent = viewParent;
        }

        public CustomMapView(Context context, GoogleMapOptions options) {
            super(context, options);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        getParent().getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        Timber.d("Inside if of action down");
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                        getParent().getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        Timber.d("Inside if of action up");

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found this as a solution -

```
class CustomMapView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?): MapView(context, attrs) {

override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    this.performClick()
    when (ev.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ->         // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
            this.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ->         // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
            this.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
    }

    // Handle MapView's touch events.
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
    return true
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get almost square MapView inside NestedScrollView.

```
    //Fix map height
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mapView.getLayoutParams();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    lp.height = metrics.widthPixels;
    mapView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```