# ESRI map inside a Nested Scroll View

Tags: android, android-nestedscrollview, esri-maps, arcgis-android-api

I am trying to add ESRI map to my fragment which is in a NestedScrollView. It is loaded fine but when I move the map it is not moving smoothly if I remove NestedScrollView everything works fine.

Here is my ESRI map view inside NestedScrollView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_normal">

    <com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

     </com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.MapView>

 </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried by setting customTouchListener to map view by referred from [here](https://community.esri.com/thread/92940) like:

```
MyTouchListener tl = new MyTouchListener(this, mMapView);   
mMapView.setOnTouchListener(tl);
```

MyTouchListener class:

```
class MyTouchListener(context: Context, m: MapView) : DefaultMapViewOnTouchListener(context, m) {

    private var sv: NestedScrollView? = null

    override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        v?.performClick()
        sv = v!!.findViewById(R.id.nestedScrollView)
        val action = event.action
        when (action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ->
                // will disable the scrollview from being able to
                // intercept the touch events for the mapview
                sv?.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)

            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ->
                // gives control back over to the scrollview
                sv?.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
        }

        super.onTouch(v, event)
        return true
    }

}
```

But still the same issue, the map is not moving smoothly.

Comment: what ESRI means ?

Comment: ESRI is a kind of Google map Ref: https://developers.arcgis.com/android/

Comment: have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33153123/mapview-inside-nestedscrollview-not-scrolling ?

Comment: Yeah that is Google map I know about it, but here it is ESRI map

Comment: Well it is not recommended to use any map like this. Why you put it in Nested Scroll

Comment: However if you want to consider using map like this. Then use as Facebook is doing in "Place Recommendation ". They are showing places in map like Image and when user click on it a maps open separately

Comment: @ZaidMirza No, I can't use as Facebook is doing because I should use same ESRI map as already implemented the same thing in iOS app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will disable the scrollView from being able to intercept the touch events for the mapView

```
override fun onTouch(view: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    activity?.nestedScrollView?.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
    return super.onTouch(view, event)
}
```

Also do it in `addViewpointChangedListener`

```
mapView.addViewpointChangedListener {
    activity?.nestedScrollView?.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
}
```