# MapView inside scrollview is not scrolling vertically which is inside Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, scrollview, ontouchlistener

I have one Fragment and in that I have taken mapview which is inside ScrollView.
While Scrolling the mapview It doesn't scrolling vertically due to it is inside ScrollView, But It scrolls horizontally.

How to avoid this Problem ?

Comment: solution is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974983/google-maps-api-v2-supportmapfragment-inside-scrollview-users-cannot-scroll-th

Comment: Here is a better solution. Try it out, and let me know if you have any doubts.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974983/google-maps-api-v2-supportmapfragment-inside-scrollview-users-cannot-scroll-th/53411743#53411743

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line on your scrollview in order to allow only vertical scrolling.

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```