# Show full map inside a SrcollView android

Tags: android, google-maps, layout, scrollview

I'd like to use a `Google Map` inside a `ScrollView` but it seems harder than I thought. The first time I created everything and ran the app on a tablet. On the tablet, the UI looks good the map's size and the place is perfect. When I tried it a smaller device I realized that 80% size of the map is invisible. I can scroll down until the end of the screen but there is a big empty place instead of the rest of the map.

Check the xml file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:id="@+id/scrollView">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:id="@+id/relativeinfo1">

<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/titleinfo"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageinfo"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleinfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageinfo"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="phone"
    android:id="@+id/mooobil"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="phone"
    android:id="@+id/telefoneeo"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="email"
    android:id="@+id/emailese"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:id="@+id/honlapese"/>


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageinfo"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageinfo"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cimtext"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Cím: "
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>


<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/vonal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="#FFD700" />

<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/vonal2"
    android:background="#FFD700"/>



<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/relativemaplayout"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="#000000">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />


</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And check the java code here:

```
 private ScrollView mScrollView;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_service_info,parent, false);
    mScrollView = (ScrollView) v.findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
    //transparentImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.transparent_image);
    mScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

    ///// MAP /////
    double glat = 0;
    double glong = 0;


    map = ((MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    if((si.getGpslat().length()) != 0 && (si.getGpslong().length() != 0)){
        glat = Double.parseDouble(si.getGpslat());
        glong = Double.parseDouble(si.getGpslong());

        final LatLng CEL = new LatLng(glat,glong);

        if (map!=null){
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(CEL));
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(CEL ,18));
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18), 2000, null);
        }

    }else{
        relmap.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
         

    transparentImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            Log.d("action","down");
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                    mScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    Log.d("action","down");
                    return false;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                    mScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    Log.d("action","up");
                    return true;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    mScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    Log.d("action","move");
                    return false;

                default:
                    return true;
            }
        }
    });

    transparentImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "anyád", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

Is it possible to show the full map in a `SrcollView` without using tablets?

This is how it's look like:

[image]

Comment: can you post one screen short ,let me see how its looking

Comment: can u add a screen shot

Comment: Yes I added a screen shot. I hope you can help me

Comment: where is the blank space?

Comment: @VV on the bottom of the screenshot

Comment: The map you see under the second yellow line is only a part of the map. The end of the map should be on the bottom of the screen.

Comment: full of white can you please change the background

Comment: @J.Doe did you try to call mapview.invalidate(), when map partially or fully visible on the screen? It should work.

Comment: @Michael Spitsin No I did not. I'll try it now!

Comment: If you want to know how to detect visibility of view inside of scrollView, check, please, this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628800/android-how-to-check-if-a-view-inside-of-scrollview-is-visible

Comment: hey try my answer.i think its layout alignment issues.

Comment: @ Jithu P.S I'm trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:id="@+id/scrollView">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:id="@+id/relativeinfo1">


<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/titleinfo"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageinfo"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleinfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageinfo"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="phone"
        android:id="@+id/cimtext"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="phone"
    android:id="@+id/mooobil"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="phone"
    android:id="@+id/telefoneeo"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="email"
    android:id="@+id/emailese"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:id="@+id/honlapese"/>


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageinfo"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageinfo"/>


<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/vonal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="#FFD700" />

<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/vonal2"
    android:background="#FFD700"/>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/relativemaplayout"
    android:clickable="true">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/transparent_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@color/transparent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativemaplayout"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relativemaplayout"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/relativemaplayout"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relativemaplayout"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relativemaplayout"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/relativemaplayout"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And you need to add this to the Fragment:

```
transparentImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            Log.d("action","down");
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                    mScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    Log.d("action","down");
                    return false;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                    mScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    Log.d("action","up");
                    return true;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    mScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    Log.d("action","move");
                    return false;

                default:
                    return true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:id="@+id/relativeinfo1">

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/titleinfo"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageinfo"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleinfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageinfo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="phone"
        android:id="@+id/mooobil"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="phone"
        android:id="@+id/telefoneeo"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="email"
        android:id="@+id/emailese"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:id="@+id/honlapese"/>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageinfo"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageinfo"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cimtext"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Cím: "
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>


    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/vonal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#FFD700" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/vonal2"
        android:background="#FFD700"/>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:id="@+id/relativemaplayout"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="#000000">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

update

if still you have problem please refer this and try

[Google Maps API v2 SupportMapFragment inside ScrollView - users cannot scroll the map vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974983/google-maps-api-v2-supportmapfragment-inside-scrollview-users-cannot-scroll-th)

Comment: Now I can't scroll down so I can only see the top of the map. So the map's size is the same as before.

Comment: try to change the fragment width to 
android:layout_height="match_content"

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but it's still wrong. No matter if I set the fragment width to  `android:layout_height="match_content" ` I still can't scroll down so I still don't see the map. Have you any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think it`s because of your layout_height setting for fragment.That cause some measure error.

Try set layout_height to a certain dp.

such as:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="300dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/relativemaplayout"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="#000000">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```