# MapView and ScollView conflicting

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-scrollview

I'm trying creating `MapView` and other views like `Button`, `EditText`, etc.. inside the `ScrollView`. The problem is that the user won't be easily **zoom in/out** the map manually because it's conflicting with `ScrollView`. I want to lock the `ScrollView` from scrolling when `MapView` is being touched by finger. Is that possible?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025859/scrollview-is-catching-touch-event-for-google-map

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21669617/3663773 . It worked for me.

Comment: yap, that's what i need. Thank you so much. :)