# How to prevent onTouchEvent() method to be called for more than one views at once?

Tags: android, touch, touch-event

I'm using a `ViewPager` and in one of my pages I have a `View` with overriden `onTouchEvent()` method.

Now when user moves his finger on a screen, `onTouchEvent()` of my `View` is being called, but also `ViewPager` is moving a page to left or right. I'd like to prevent somehow `ViewPager` from calling it's `onTouchEvent()` method IF a user is touching my `View`'s area. Is it possible?

Comment: put some code with question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewPager` will by default intercept all touch events. In fact, if you put anything inside anything else that scrolls, the container will intercept the touch event. You can override this behavior in certain cases. There is a similar problem with a solution here that might help you:

[ViewPager intercepts all x-axis onTouch events. How to disable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122460/viewpager-intercepts-all-x-axis-ontouch-events-how-to-disable)

Comment: Thanks, solution from the other question worked fine for me :-)