# how to disable viewpager adapter on touching specific views?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager which switches between tabs when swiping left/right.In my second tab, i have some custom views which have listeners for pinching and dragging but when i try to pinch or drag, the viewpager starts to swipe the page.

A solution comes to my mind is to disable swiping when touching those specific views and only swipe when touching outside those views.Is this possible?

**Updated:**
@Asok kindly provided the solution. But then updated the code which wouldnt work in my case so i post the previous piece of code which worked for me:

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {
private boolean swipeable = true;

public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

// Call this method in your motion events when you want to disable or enable
// It should work as desired.
public void setSwipeable(boolean swipeable) {
    this.swipeable = swipeable;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
    return (this.swipeable) ? super.onInterceptTouchEvent(arg0) : false;
}
```

Lets suppose i have a draggable view and i need to disable swipping when dragging start and re enable when dragging finished so in TouchEvent of my so called view:

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
//disable swiping when the button is touched
((ActivityOriginal) getActivity()).setSwipeable(false);
//the rest of the code...
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
//re enable swipping when the touch is stopped
//the rest of the code...
((ActivityOriginal) getActivity()).setSwipeable(true);
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This first thing that comes to mind for me is to have a custom `ViewPager` in which, when your touch listeners get notified of a specific event you could set the `swipeable` `boolean` in `ViewPager` to false and set it back to true whichever way best fits your application.

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {
    private boolean swipeable = true;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    // Call this method in your motion events when you want to disable or enable
    // It should work as desired.
    public void setSwipeable(boolean swipeable) {
        this.swipeable = swipeable;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
        return (this.swipeable) ? super.onInterceptTouchEvent(arg0) : false; 
    }

}
```

---

Make sure to change your layout file to show:

```
<com.your.package.CustomViewPager .. />
```

Instead of:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager .. />
```

---

**Edit 2**

Here is my setup (Working with the above `CustomViewPager`):

```
CustomViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the CustomViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

}

public void swipeOn(View v) {
    mViewPager.setSwipeable(true);
}

public void swipeOff(View v) {
    mViewPager.setSwipeable(false);
}
```

The above shown `onCreate` is in my `MainActivity` class which extends `FragmentActivity`  and implements `ActionBar.TabListener`

Comment: @asok how can i access to the customviewpager instance(which is created in the activity) from different fragments?

Comment: @Asok unfortunately none of UI elements react to touch,even buttons and list views after just using the customviewpager instead of viewpager.

Comment: @afterburner Sorry about that, instead of `onInterceptTouchEvent` try `onTouchEvent`, I tested and it was working for me by disabling swipe and no other touch event.

Comment: @androiddeveloper After I corrected myself it is working and able to be switched on and off.

Comment: @afterburner Also as a side note, when disabling the swipe, as I show, it still allows for the user to press the tab to switch pages if you use tabs. This is something I use in my application, should work for your purpose. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @Asok onInterceptTouchEvent did the trick for me but onTouchEvent(when the sweap was set to false the tabs were still sweapable but the sweap was slow like 1mm in each sweap).so i used onInterceptTouchEvent .Thank you for helping out. Just hope i could give you a lot more points for solving this problem.

Comment: I am facing similar problem (like http://stackoverflow.com/q/8122460/2624806) where view getting shifting in x-direction even after disable it...any solution/suggestion here>?

Comment: Nice one .Helped me a lot .+1

Answer (score 35):

I am using [requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent%28boolean%29) int the onTouchEvent listener of the view that also has drag events.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    ViewParent parent = getParent(); 
    // or get a reference to the ViewPager and cast it to ViewParent

    parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

    // let this view deal with the event or
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: you save my days. Thanks :)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am using like this

```
public void setSwipeable(boolean swipeable)
{
    this.swipeable = swipeable;
}

@Override
public void scrollTo(int x, int y){
    if (swipeable){
        super.scrollTo(x, y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the positions on which you don't want to intercept touch events in the view pager you can do something like I did.

```
 @Override
 public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
    if(arg0.getY()>getHeight()/2)return false;
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(arg0);
}
```