# Swipe ListView 47deg inside a fragment of ViewPager

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, fragment

Im trying to implement Swipe ListView open source library by 47Deg inside a fragment of ViewPager. I tried this library in simple Activity and it work flawless. References to this library are follow:

[Library GitHub](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview)

[Tutorial](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-swipe-listview/)

[YouTube Tutorial](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-swipe-listview/)

**Senario**

As I mentioned I want to implement it inside fragment of ViewPager but when I swipe on item of a list the view page slides away. I wanted to wipe list item when list item is touched and swipe fragment otherwise.

**What I have already done**

I created a custom class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager{} and disabled the swipe on touch by using the solution provided [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342630/how-to-disable-viewpager-adapter-on-touching-specific-views).
I also tried tweaking around with onTouch, Clickable tags and other thing which I could do best as I'm a newbie.

Help me regarding this issue.

Comment: Hi, i am also facing the same issue. Can you help me if you solved this issue ?

Answer (score 5):

in class class SwipeListViewTouchListener in method     public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
I added         view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
and it works for me. Give it a try may be it works for you too.

Comment: actually adding this in onTouch(...) at the end of if (allowSwipe && rect.contains(x, y))  statement right before break; is better since it will allow swiping if the list takes the entire fragment but its element don't fill the entire space and we click in that empty space