# android: How to disable on click of Viewpager left and right preview?

Tags: java, android

```
mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                adPageSelectListener.onPageChanged(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: [Please refer to this link in following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342630/how-to-disable-viewpager-adapter-on-touching-specific-views)

Answer (score -1):

You can create your own NonSwipableViewPager like this:

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {
public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
}
```

just override `OnTouchEvent` and `onInterceptTouchEvent` method and return `false`.

Comment: I want to disable On click of left and right preview. Only The visible view pager should take On Click.

Comment: Click on What, ViewPager?

Comment: ViewPager adapter containing fragment (Inside fragment I have my views)

Comment: can you upload screenshot of your View Pager?

Comment: I have my viewpager looks like this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914609/viewpager-with-previous-and-next-page-boundaries