# OnTouch event on Screen

Tags: android, android-viewpager, ontouchlistener

I have xml in which I have 2 relative layouts, the first one is map(using map fragments) and the second one is ViewPager layout. I added button to map to hide map when clicked, now I want a method to get back the map layout by sweep down the screen.

I tried setting onTouchListener to relative layout but it is not working, also tried implementing OnTouchListener

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnTouchListener

it is not working! how to achieve this?

```
  @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        x= event.getX();
        y=event.getY();

        switch(event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                sX = event.getX();
                sY = event.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                fX = event.getX();
                fY = event.getY();
                if(fX-sX == 0 || fX-sX > 0 || fX-sX <0)
                    if(fY-sY < 0)
                    {

                        if(mapview.getVisibility()==View.GONE)
                        {
                            mapview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }
                    }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: also I want to know what exactly the ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP mean?

Comment: `if(fX-sX == 0 || fX-sX > 0 || fX-sX <0)` Umm, what? Why not just use `if(true)` or leave it out altogether?

Comment: On topic, though, your `ViewPager` is probably intercepting the touch event. Can you log this method to see if it's even called?

Comment: I'm even unable to determine whether this method is being called or not.

Comment: add a line to it that says `Log.d("TouchTest", "called!");`, and look for that in logcat while running. Side note: You may want to read up on logging/debugging techniques.

Comment: nope! I don't see the message! 
Side note: @Geobits thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Then it's being intercepted. You can google around to override that, or this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8122680/752320

Comment: thanks a lot! @Geobits, between I have a ListView in the ViewPager, so I cannot do that!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using a `ListView`, `ViewPager`, *and* scrolling gestures all on the same screen. It will just confuse the system, and is generally not recommended. It might be easier to figure out another design for this interaction.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36570/discussion-between-vkn-and-geobits)

Answer (score 0):

Post your code, btw in simple way, ACTION_DOWN is when you touch the screen, ACTION_UP is when you finger release the screen. [Look here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)

Comment: To be more exact, `ACTION_DOWN` is when the *first* finger touches the screen, and `ACTION_UP` is when the *last* finger lifts. For anything in between, you need to use the `ACTION_POINTER_xxx` options instead.