# HorizontalScrollView inside PagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, touch

When I add `ScrollView` inside pager and scroll right it is scrolling between pages, and not inside the `ScrollView`.

- How do I prevent scrolling between pages until the condition happens?
- How do I make it scroll inside `ScrollView` until reaching the end, then scrolling between pages?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920137/android-viewpager-and-horizontalscrollview