# How to handle touch event HorizontalListScrollview or horizontalListview inside Viewpager in android?

Tags: android, touch, android-viewpager

I have implemented `HorizontalListView` inside `ViewPager`. `ViewPager` works fine but a child of `ViewPager` (`HorizontalListView`) doesn't scroll. Instead the whole page scrolls to next. How to solve touch event when parent and child both posses touch event?

In my case `ViewPager` is parent view which inflate the `pager.xml`

pager.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.geekyouup.paug.awesomepager.HorizontialListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="135dip"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="left" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sagfjsdkfksjdfhkjs" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="he ha ha ha" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: just think, both controls are consuming "horizontal touch moves" so i think it is not possible to make it work

Comment: :( is it really impossible?? isn't there any alternative to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920137/android-viewpager-and-horizontalscrollview)

and give him a thanks who make it possible :)