# How cand i add swipe up/down detection on a viewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I implemented a normal `ViewPager` with default swipes from left to right. However, I need to detect when the user swipes up and down without dispatching the default left/right functions. How can I do that?

Comment: please reffer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures

Comment: please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13584056/4748607)

Comment: the problem with this approach is that when you set the touch listener to your ViewPager it disables the default left to right swipe gestures

Comment: Please refer this :https://medium.com/@jimitpatel/viewpager-with-vertical-swiping-ability-e40200094281

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to handle right to left swipe gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a class `SimpleGestureFilter`

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class SimpleGestureFilter extends SimpleOnGestureListener{

     public final static int SWIPE_UP    = 1;
     public final static int SWIPE_DOWN  = 2;
     public final static int SWIPE_LEFT  = 3;
     public final static int SWIPE_RIGHT = 4;

     public final static int MODE_TRANSPARENT = 0;
     public final static int MODE_SOLID       = 1;
     public final static int MODE_DYNAMIC     = 2;

     private final static int ACTION_FAKE = -13; //just an unlikely number
     private int swipe_Min_Distance = 100;
     private int swipe_Max_Distance = 350;
     private int swipe_Min_Velocity = 100;

 private int mode             = MODE_DYNAMIC;
 private boolean running      = true;
 private boolean tapIndicator = false;

 private Activity context;
 private GestureDetector detector;
 private SimpleGestureListener listener;

 public SimpleGestureFilter(Activity context,SimpleGestureListener sgl) {

  this.context = context;
  this.detector = new GestureDetector(context, this);
  this.listener = sgl;
 }

 public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

   if(!this.running)
  return; 

   boolean result = this.detector.onTouchEvent(event);

   if(this.mode == MODE_SOLID)
    event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
   else if (this.mode == MODE_DYNAMIC) {

     if(event.getAction() == ACTION_FAKE)
       event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
     else if (result)
       event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
     else if(this.tapIndicator){
      event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
      this.tapIndicator = false;
     }

   }
   //else just do nothing, it's Transparent
 }

 public void setMode(int m){
  this.mode = m;
 }

 public int getMode(){
  return this.mode;
 }

 public void setEnabled(boolean status){
  this.running = status;
 }

 public void setSwipeMaxDistance(int distance){
  this.swipe_Max_Distance = distance;
 }

 public void setSwipeMinDistance(int distance){
  this.swipe_Min_Distance = distance;
 }

 public void setSwipeMinVelocity(int distance){
  this.swipe_Min_Velocity = distance;
 }

 public int getSwipeMaxDistance(){
  return this.swipe_Max_Distance;
 }

 public int getSwipeMinDistance(){
  return this.swipe_Min_Distance;
 }

 public int getSwipeMinVelocity(){
  return this.swipe_Min_Velocity;
 }

 @Override
     public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
       float velocityY) {

      final float xDistance = Math.abs(e1.getX() - e2.getX());
      final float yDistance = Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY());

      if(xDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance || yDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance)
       return false;

      velocityX = Math.abs(velocityX);
      velocityY = Math.abs(velocityY);
            boolean result = false;

      if(velocityX > this.swipe_Min_Velocity && xDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance){
       if(e1.getX() > e2.getX()) // right to left
        this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_LEFT);
       else
        this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_RIGHT);

       result = true;
      }
      else if(velocityY > this.swipe_Min_Velocity && yDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance){
       if(e1.getY() > e2.getY()) // bottom to up
        this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_UP);
       else
        this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_DOWN);

       result = true;
      }

       return result;
     }

 @Override
 public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
  this.tapIndicator = true;
  return false;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent arg) {
  this.listener.onDoubleTap();;
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent arg) {
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent arg) {

  if(this.mode == MODE_DYNAMIC){        // we owe an ACTION_UP, so we fake an
     arg.setAction(ACTION_FAKE);      //action which will be converted to an ACTION_UP later.
     this.context.dispatchTouchEvent(arg);
  }  

  return false;
 }

    static interface SimpleGestureListener{
     void onSwipe(int direction);
     void onDoubleTap();
 }

}
```

then in your `viewPager` `onCreate`

```
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.swipe_screen);

            // Detect touched area 
            detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this,this);
    }

 @Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
    // Call onTouchEvent of SimpleGestureFilter class
     this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
   return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
}
@Override
 public void onSwipe(int direction) {
  String str = "";

  switch (direction) {

  case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT : str = "Swipe Right";
                                           break;
  case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT :  str = "Swipe Left";
                                                 break;
  case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_DOWN :  str = "Swipe Down";
                            // your code for Swipe Down
                                                 break;
  case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_UP :    str = "Swipe Up";
                              // your code for Swipe Up
                                                 break;

  }
   Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }

 @Override
 public void onDoubleTap() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Double Tap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

the codes in your viewPager replace the comments with your code..

```
case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_DOWN :  str = "Swipe Down";
                            // your code for Swipe Down
  case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_UP :    str = "Swipe Up";
                      // your code for Swipe Up
```

Comment: please mark the answer .. if it helped you...  @Vlad

Comment: @amit How is the detector in `onCreate` method defined ?

Comment: in your viewpager onCreate add the code  `detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this,this);` to define a detector

Answer (score 1):

Now it is lot easier to add up and down swipe in ViewPager. Just move to [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2). Use `RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>` to fill your data.

```
pager.setAdapter(adptr);
pager.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
```

Comment: I feel the question was about detecting the up/down gestures and not making it vertical. After making it vertically oriented how would you identify if the user swipes up or down?