# Design a HorizontalScrollView inside of ViewPager or use fragments:

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I need to design the following screen, and I need your advice:

[image]

**Explanation:**

The title is static/fixed and I don't need to do anything with it.

**Yellow:** this is the interesting part, I need to design a `ViewPager` like screen that has the capability to scroll left/right for Max 4 screens.

**Red:** In every screen I need to add a Table/Grid that can be scrollable as well if it's not fits screen size.

**Green:** The page switching can be done using the green buttons in the bottom of the screen or by scrolling the `ViewPager`.

**The Question Is:** Can this behavior be achieve using a `ViewPager` or should I use `Fragments`? If Fragment is the way to go, then how would I implement the page switching using the sliding gesture? if it's a `ViewPager` then how to add the inside scrolling and how to control it using the buttons at the bottom?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: If those tables/grids need to be scrollable on the X axis(filling the entire width) then I don't know how you could implement this as you'll not be able to decide which widget should be allowed to be scrolled. If the tables/grids will be scrollable only vertically than use a `ViewPager`.

Comment: actually I have stumbled upon the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920137/android-viewpager-and-horizontalscrollview and people say there that it possible, I never tried it so I opened this question to see people opinions, and maybe get an idea of what way would be better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this should be tackled with a *Non Swipeable* `ViewPager`. There is no way the view pager *and* the underlying `Fragment`s should respond to the swiping gesture. The methods to override to disable swiping within the `ViewPager` are:

1. [`onTouchEvent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) - returns `false`.
2. [`onInterceptTouchEvent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent))- returns `false`.

Refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s) for more information on how to achieve this.

Next up you want to be using `Fragment`s within each of your pager holders. So we're building the following layout:

[image]

Within the parent activity a `FragmentPagerAdapter` is instantiated and your tabs added with a tag:

#### Activity changes

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    final FragmentPagerAdapter myTabAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(
            <Your ViewPager View>, <Your activity context, this>);
    myTabAdapter.addTab(getActionBar().newTab(), "YOUR TAG", "Your Title");
    // etc...
}
```

So this gives us the frame of the diagram above. A hosting activity, containing a `ViewPager` and the underlying tabs. Next up is getting the `Fragment`s (containing your tables) into each of the respective tabs. This is handled by the `FragmentPagerAdapter` implementation:

#### Fragment adapter (inner class to activity):

```
private class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
        ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    /**
     * Constructs a pager adapter to back a {@link ViewPager}.
     * 
     * @param pager
     *            The {@link ViewPager} widget.
     * @param activityContext
     *            The context the widget is being added under.
     */
    public SpotMenuFragmentPagerAdapter(final ViewPager pager,
            final Context activityContext) {
        super(getFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(this);
        this.context = activityContext;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a tab to the hosting activity action bar.
     * 
     * @param newTab
     *            The tab to add.
     * @param tag
     *            The tab tag for id purposes.
     * @param label
     *            The label of the tab displayed to the user.
     */
    public void addTab(final ActionBar.Tab newTab, final String tag,
            final String label) {
        newTab.setTag(tag);
        newTab.setText(label);
        newTab.setTabListener(this);
        getSupportActionBar().addTab(newTab);
    }

    /**
     * This is where you do the work of building the correct fragment based
     * on the tab currently selected.
     * 
     * @see FragmentPagerAdapter#getItem(int)
     */
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(final int position) {
        final Tab tab = getActionBar().getTabAt(position);
        if ("MY TAG".equals(tab.getTag().toString()) {
            // instantiate the fragment (table) for "MY TAG"
        } else {
            // instantiate something else...
        }
    }

    /**
     * One fragment per tab.
     * 
     * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#getCount()
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return getSupportActionBar().getTabCount();
    }

    /**
     * @see ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener#onPageScrollStateChanged(int)
     */
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int arg0) {
        // No-op.
    }

    /**
     * @see ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener#onPageScrolled(int, float, int)
     */
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(final int arg0, final float arg1,
            final int arg2) {
        // No-op.
    }

    /**
     * @see ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener#onPageSelected(int)
     */
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(final int position) {
        getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    /**
     * @see TabListener#onTabSelected(app.ActionBar.Tab,
     *      app.FragmentTransaction)
     */
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(final Tab tab, final FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    /**
     * @see TabListener#onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab,
     *      app.FragmentTransaction)
     */
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(final Tab tab, final FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // No-op.
    }

    /**
     * @see TabListener#onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab,app.FragmentTransaction)
     */
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(final Tab tab, final FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // No-op.
    }
}
```

So hopefully by this point we have an activity hosting a 'non-swipeable' view pager and a mechanism for switching tabs in the form of the tab bar underneath the title (or alongside depending on the screen size). From this point I am sure you could customise to replace the tab bar with some navigational arrows.

*Note:* A lot of that was written from memory but hopefully I've conveyed the gist of where I would go with this.

### Update

In response to the updated question: you can set the tab to be any old view. Set the [TabSpec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html) accordingly. Apologies I haven't used this myself.

Comment: actually there is a solution for swipe problem you are talking about, look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920137/android-viewpager-and-horizontalscrollview, I have not checked it yet. But if I use a ViewPager, and I don't have an action bar, How do I place my page switching buttons in the bottom of the screen and customize them?

Comment: @EmilAdz - Here is a [non-action bar example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html)

Comment: what is the diffrence between "FragmentStatePagerAdapter" and "FragmentPagerAdapter"?

Comment: Hey Emil- I could repeat the docs here but the explanations are easy to get at. The ````FragmentStatePagerAdapter```` is kinder to memory when considering many pages at the expense of slower initialisation of the fragment (by virtue of the fact that only the state - not the entire component - is held in memory)

Comment: so for my case (4 fragments at most) it will be better (from point of performance) to use FragmentPagerAdapter?

Comment: Yes. The two are interchangeable with the underlying implementation transparent to the developer.

Comment: I'm still struggling with the horizontal swap, but the bounty is yours for you informative answer on FragmentViewPager that helped to do a lot of work on this screen. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use HorizontalScrollView which it'll contain a LinearLayout and the Linear is the one that will contain your individual elements

The XML would see something like this

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset">

       <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/content_scroll"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Thats the wrong way. Use Fragements and not overloaded Layouts with need 1 sec to load.