# Can I use Horizontal Scrollview Inside a Viewpager in Android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scrollview

Is it possible to make a horizontal `scrollview` inside viewpager in android ? 
The `HorizontalScrollView` should scroll until it reaches its edges, then on next scrolling, should load the next viewpager view.

Comment: you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382753/design-a-horizontalscrollview-inside-of-viewpager-or-use-fragments)
maybe ,it can help you

Answer (score 9):

your can just make custom xxViewpager extends Viewpager, and Override the canScroll method like below:

```
 @Override
        protected boolean canScroll(View v, boolean checkV, int dx, int x, int y) {
                if (v instanceof HorizontalScrollView) {
                        return true;
                }
                return super.canScroll(v, checkV, dx, x, y);
        }
```

Comment: This helped me - after around 3h of looking for a solution to having a HorizontalScrollView (containing an ImageView with a very big image) inside a ViewPager. Thank you :)