# Android: How to intercept touch event in ViewPager2

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, swipe-gesture, android-viewpager2

How to prevent swiping in [androidx ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2) when the touch event is coming from inside a nested view (e.g. a HorizontalScrollView, etc)?

I expected this to be possible by overriding `ViewPager2.onInterceptTouchEvent()` but since ViewPager2 is `final` it cannot be subclassed.

The existing solutions (listed below) deal with the older [ViewPager](http://androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager) which *can* be subclassed.

As suggested in one of the answers I have tried:

```java
    private ViewPager2 viewPager2;

    ...
    HorizontalScrollView nestedScrollView = pagerView.findViewById(R.id.scrollview);

    nestedScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            viewPager2.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }
    });

// nestedScrollView - the HorizontalScrollView inside a ViewPager2 item
// viewPager2 - the ViewPager2 instance
```

but this does not seem to have any effect.

ViewPager2 has onInterceptTouchEvent() [inherited from ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) but I don't see a way to override it on a final class.

Reimplementing the entire ViewPager2 does not seem like a sane solution — the original class is 1607 lines long and moreover it's using classes which are not exported by the package.

Other similar questions I've looked at:

- [android: ViewPager and HorizontalScrollVIew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920137/android-viewpager-and-horizontalscrollview)
- [Can I use Horizontal Scrollview Inside a Viewpager in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22781496/can-i-use-horizontal-scrollview-inside-a-viewpager-in-android)
- [Prevent Swiping of ViewPager2 when onTouch of inner view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60328756/prevent-swiping-of-viewpager2-when-ontouch-of-inner-view)
- [ViewPager2 with horizontal scrollView inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57587618/viewpager2-with-horizontal-scrollview-inside)

Comment: viewPager.userInputEnabled = false has not solved your problem? you mean nested scrolling inside a fragment in your view pager triggers swiping?

Comment: @BitaMirshafiee: I need to set `viewPager.userInputEnabled = false/true` dynamically depending on where the touch event originated from: when the swipe starts in the nested HorizontalScrollVIew then it should be `false`, otherwise `true`.

Comment: @ccpizza did you solve this issue. Now I have similar issue, BottomSheetDialogFragment with horizontal ViewPager2. Horizontal ViewPager2 catch vertical scroll and I don't have possibility to override onInterceptTouchEvent, because ViewPager2 class is final

Comment: to allow bottomsheet be draggable over viewpager2: 
(bottomsheet.getChildAt(0) as RecyclerView).isNestedScrollingEnabled = false