# android:How to solve ViewPager TouchEvent conflict with my custom View?

Tags: android

In my application I have a custom `View` (that extends `ImageView`) and in it we handle the touch events to move Image.

Then I make `ViewPager` to slide right or left to show the next layout.

The custom `View` `onTouchEvent` code works fine by itself. The `ViewPager` code also works fine. However, if I add them both, my custom `View` code for move image left or right stops working.

Here's the code for the `OnTouchEvent` in the custom `View`:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    super.onTouchEvent(event);

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        //TODO
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        //TODO
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        //TODO
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Hoping for any help!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this post:

[android: ViewPager and HorizontalScrollVIew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920137/android-viewpager-and-horizontalscrollview)

there are a couple of solution how to handle situation when the `ViewPager` contents is also scroll-able.

you will have to create your own custom `ViewPager` and override the `onInterceptTouchEvent` method.