# Table content in webview is not scroling properly

Tags: android, webview, html-table

I have a `webview` in that I am loading a webpage which has a table of values which can be scrolled horizontally. In `webview` it is not able to scroll properly. Webview is inside a `fragment` in `ViewPager`. When I try to scroll it will be moved to the next `Viewpager` item. This is how the webpage looks.

[image]

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920137/android-viewpager-and-horizontalscrollview

Comment: @Aju How do resolve the above problem?